# Serialization issue in entity framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have next issue, I have simple MVC from 2 clases below

```
public class Manager
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Employee> EmplCol { get; set; }
    public Manager() 
    {
        this.EmplCol = new List<Employee>();
    }
}
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Profeesion { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public Employee() { }
}
```

and next **entity framework** context

```
public class EFContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

And after adding autogenerated `WebApi 2` controller to my project with `Manager` as `Model` and `EFContext` as Context class I get Serialization exception. What must I do to enable serialization in this case ?

Comment: I doubt that even compiles as the constructor for `Manager` tries to set `this.SheepCol` but there isn't a field or property called `SheepCol`

Comment: @AndyNichols sory for this, have changed it. Actualy problem with proxy that created during serialization, when I try this `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` it fix problem but in that case I get empty `EmplCol`

Comment: post your code for your controller, and please post  the full exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Manager
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Employee> EmplCol { get; set; }
}
```

If it works, i'll edit and explain why,

Answer (score 0):

In addition to user2997779's answer: if you're receiving "self referencing loop detected for property..." exception message, this page has several approaches how you could handle it: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Loop-Reference-handling-in-caaffaf7